# IIS - Handling the load for a Chat service

Tags: wcf, web-services, performance, iis

We have a Chat Service which is written in WCF and we have hosted it in a separate IIS site. Now I'm planning to add logging features (in a MS SQL Server database) across the entire chat application and I don't want to affect the performance of the core chat service. I'm writing a separate WCF service which take cares of writing entries in the database.

My question is that can I host the new logging service as a separate IIS site to handle incoming requests without sharing the load with the regular service or can I host in a separate virtual directory under the same site?

Since the chat application is real time want to be very careful in the performance since

> Requesting logging service + accessing
>   database = some latency

which I don't want to be included in the main service. Any suggestions?

**More Explanation**

Let me tell you why I want to go for a separate service.

If log and chat are in the same service -

[image]

Now my point is that if both the services are hosted under same site (which has a single entry point to IIS) will it be better? Or hosting them as different sites is better?

Comment: Why do you implement logging as service instead of directly adding logging to the Chat service?

Comment: I want to add that logging latency to the original chat service cycle. It affects the application's responsiveness.

Comment: Please check my explanation. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sites in IIS are really just presentation entities, in that you may want to bind one app to *site1.example.com* and another to *site2.example.com*.  "Load" in terms of server resources are directly related to **worker processes**, which are bound to **application pools**.

So combining all that, you can put your new logging service wherever it makes most sense.  Assign it to a separate app pool and it will not "share" resources with your other service in terms of IIS or ASP.NET piping.  (Obviously apps on the same server are competing for a finite # of resources, but that doesn't seem to be your concern)

That said, I can't quite understand the relationship of the system you'd laid out where this would make sense.  Wouldn't logging requests be a part of the app itself?  Or does your client maintain a connection to both the chat service and logging service? (which seems like an odd architecture)

Comment: Not wrong, just a matter of opinion.  I think both of us assumed you would be doing some DB work in the Chat service itself (otherwise you basically just have a "bounce" service).  All said, thats an architectural decision for you.  In terms of load/etc, everything I offered in this answer is still correct.  However you split it up, IIS sites won't matter, just make sure your application pools are separate